# flex scatter plot?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Does anyone know of a good Scatter Plot/Chart component that I can use with Flex Builder 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Flex Visualization stuff has a scatter chart: [Plot Charts](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_01.html)

There is also Flare, if you're looking for a free open source solution: [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)

Answer (score 0):

PlotCharts are included in the flex charting components:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_10.html